# JS/jQuery - Reset MouseLeave when I Start MouseOver again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, mouseover

```
$("#profile_bar").mouseover(function()
{
    $("#profile_bar")stop(true).animate({
        marginTop : "0px"
    }, 300);
});

$("#profile_bar").mouseleave(function()
{
    $("#profile_bar").stop(true).delay(2000).animate({
        marginTop : "-70px"
    }, 300);
});
```

At the moment I have the code you see above. What I want to happen is:

When I hover the div #profile_bar, it moves 70 pixels down. When I go away from that div, and go back to it, within 2 seconds, It has to stop the MouseLeave function and actually nothing should happen.

Can someone give me a hint or help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var timeouts = {};
$("#profile_bar").mouseover(function()
{
    clearTimeout(timeouts['profile_bar']);
    $("#profile_bar").stop(true).animate({
        marginTop : "0px"
    }, 300);
});

$("#profile_bar").mouseleave(function()
{
    timeouts['profile_bar'] = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#profile_bar").stop(true).animate({
            marginTop : "-70px"
        }, 300);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`clearQueue`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) on your `mouseover`, that will remove any effects that were queued for later execution so the mouseleave animation won't happen.

**Edit:** I tested my suggestion on jsFiddle and saw no difference between using `clearQueue` or not. Then I saw that the [api docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) says (emphasis mine):

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—**it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay**—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

So, AlienWebguy's answer is what you need actually...

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and for trying to help me with this!